# OutOfMemoryException on adding to AD group

Tags: c#, active-directory, out-of-memory, active-directory-group

I have a console application which is runs as a Windows Task.

One of the actions done is to add a computer to an AD group.

The code below does that:

```
public static bool AddToGroup(string machineName, string groupName)
        {
            using (
                var context = new PrincipalContext(
                    ContextType.Domain,
                    Helper.GetAppSetting("Domain"),
                    Helper.GetAppSetting("ServiceAccountLogonName"),
                    Helper.GetAppSetting("ServiceAccountPassword")))
            {
                using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
                {
                    using (var computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, machineName))
                    {
                        if (group == null || computer == null)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        group.Members.Add(computer);
                        group.Save();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This function and the task have been running without an issue.

> This task failed once with the following error message: Exception of
>   type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Is it because of the of the machine or group which is being searched for?
Is there an issue in the code as it is which makes it susceptible to OutOfMemoryExceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue on the computer.

The paging file on the drive where the executable was running was set to None.

I am open to hear other possible issues here